# Getting Exception in tread Thread-1 where a try should catch the error

Tags: python-3.x, raspbian

I am using [Wifi](https://github.com/rockymeza/wifi) module and using this helper [file](https://gist.github.com/taylor224/516de7dd0b707bc0b1b3) I want to connect to wifi with the function Connect() it does work but when there is a problem the function should return False but for some reason, I am getting this error `wifi.exceptions.ConnectionError....` as I can tell the helper file should catch that error and then return False to my main program. As stated in line 57 and 69 `except wifi.exceptions.ConnectionError:` instead it is just crashing my program.

```
 import WifiHandler

 isConnected = WifiHandler.Connect("wifiNetwork","Password")

 if isConnect == True:
      do Somthing
```

and this is the error

```
TraceBack (most recent call last):
 File "test.py". line 11, in <module>
  isConnected = WifiHandler.Connect(ssid,password)
 File "/home/pi/WifiHandler.py", line 43, in Connect
    savedcell.activate()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/wifi/scheme.py", line 176. in activate
     return self.parse_ifup_output(ifup_output)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/wifi/scheme.py" line 183, in parse_ifuo_output
     raise ConnectionError("failed to connect to %r" % self)
     wifi.exceptions.ConnectionError: Failed to connect to Scheme(interface='wlan0',name ='SSIDName', options={'wpa-psk':'32nnj3323jej222n4n2n421353535353535353535353535353', 'wpa-ssid': 'SSIDName' , 'wireless-channel':'auto'})
```

Comment: Can you show the whole exception you get? And having your code could really help us help you.

Comment: In the 'helper file', when the part `savedcell = FindFromSavedList(cell.ssid)` is executed, it finds something and calls the saved cell's activate function. You never reach the lines 57 and 69.

Comment: Thank you, The person that created the helper file assumed that part of the code would not give an error I added a `try:  except wifi.exceptions.ConnectionError:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thank to [Morb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4733992/morb). I fix the problem.

In the helper file it was not catching the error for savedcells

```
      if savedcell:
            savedcell.activate()
            return cell
```

it should be

```
 if savedcell:
        try:
           savedcell.activate()
        except wifi.exceptions.ConnectionError:

            return False

        return cell
```